# Hide Price from WooCommerce Product Add-ons Dropdown if it's equal to zero

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, add-on, price

I found this post: [Remove price from Woocommerce variable product dropdown menu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/193721/remove-price-from-woocommerce-variable-product-dropdown-menu), but it hides ALL variable prices. Instead I would like to hide the variable price if it is $0.00.

Can anyone help me with this?

---

**Edit:**

I didn't realize that the variation prices weren't part of WooCommerce. I am using WooCommerce Product Add-ons. I found this snippet that will target a specific product, but I don't know how to convert it to if !$0.00 condition. This post closer identifies my issue: 
[Hide displayed product prices from Woocommerce Product Add-ons Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54951179/hide-displayed-product-prices-from-woocommerce-product-add-ons-fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Hide displayed product prices from Woocommerce Product Add-ons Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54951179/hide-displayed-product-prices-from-woocommerce-product-add-ons-fields/54951616#54951616) answer code, you can try to use something like:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_addons_option_price', 'filter_product_addons_option_price', 10, 4 );
function filter_product_addons_option_price( $price_html, $option, $i, $type ){
    if( isset($option['price']) && ! ( $option['price'] > 0 ) ) {
        $price_html = '';
    }
    return $price_html;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It could works.

Comment: Hi Loic, thanks so much for the suggestion and your help again. The option price is actually required to be set for the option to appear on the front end - so the price is set at 0.00. It seems this logic won't trigger since there is a price that is set. :-)

I also got an error for the last quote marks that I needed to remove from the if statement after $price_html, I don't know if that would have any effect.

Comment: @joy Just updated again, removed a mistake and some code that I forgot to remove.